# Using nillable elements in BizTalk expressions

Tags: xsd, biztalk

I have nillable decimal element defined in xsd schema like this:

```
<xs:element name="myDecimalValue" nillable="true" type="xs:decimal" />
```

This is distinguished field and I want to check if it is nill in expression shape. I could use xpath() function like this:

```
xpath("string(//*[local-name()='myDecimalValue']/@*[local-name()='nil'])") == "true"
```

But it looks a little bit complicated for simple null-checking. So I'm wondering if I'm missing something and there is better way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

you can try to use a decide shape instead of the xpath

your decide shape will lok like this 
just ask if myDecimalValue is null

```
 msgName.myDecimalValue != null here
```

than you can continue  your logic

if you using a  distinguished field use it its more readable for other dev

**EDIT:**

can you try
 varString = System.Convert.ToString(msgName.myDecimalValue);

and then ask if varString  is null or not

i tried   it and it compile well

hopes it help 
:)

Comment: You can't compare decimal and null. You'll get this error: `operator '!=' cannot be applied to operands of type 'System.Decimal' and 'null'`

Comment: This won't work either. Because msgName.myDecimalValue is of type System.Decimal and not System.Nullable<decimal> - there is no way System.Convert.ToString() would return null.

Answer (score 0):

I have a suspicion that this can't be achieved.

Specifically, from http://support.microsoft.com/kb/942250

> Properties that have a null value are not permitted in the message
>   context. Therefore, if a null value is written into the message
>   context, this value will be deleted.

(this is in the document section relating to Promoted and Distinguished properties, so I am assuming it is applicable to both).

So it looks like your xpath solution might be the required solution, as the distinguished property won't be in the message context anyway.

Comment: I think this is applicable only to promoted properties. Distinguished properties are not written into message context, so null values are permitted.
But anyway, looks like xpath is the only way to go here.

Comment: Related to this, recently had a case where a Distinguished field was omitted *entirely* on an incoming multipart message. An expression shape which attempted to evaluate it (msg.Part.DistinguishedField) gave a Null Reference Exception. So yes, xpath is indeed safest, unless it is also validated or pre-parsed through a map/xslt to ensure the field is correct as expected.